# Windows Phone "Alignment image" - Why?

Tags: alignment, windows-phone

I'm developing for Windows Phone 8, I've designed my application and I noticed that there is an "Assignment grid" code that can be uncommented by default on a new project.

Take a look below for the description in the file:

```
<!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
            aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
            account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
            if the System Tray is hidden.

            Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
        <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
```

This is the background image that shows when it is uncommented:

[image: Alignment grid]

I'm confused by this, why are there "common boundaries" determined by an image?  Surely the boundaries are determined within the development environment, IE the borders of the phone image?  Even on that image shown above, the default "My Application" text doesn't fit within the "alignment image".  So they're not abiding by their own alignment rule?

What am I supposed to take from this information?  By keeping everything within these boundaries I'm going to be losing half of the screen space!

Why do I have to align my controls within these boundaries, will they end up not being shown?  I thought the Windows Phones have the same resolution anyway?

**EDIT:**

I was hoping to put a notification button and indication of the current logged in username at the very top of my application like so:

[image: Menu top showing username and notifications]

The only way that I could have these inside the grid would be if I had them drooping down quite far, it wouldn't look how I want.

Should I definitely be putting everything within the grid image, if not am I heading for trouble with my implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grids are used as guidelines to make your app look aesthetically pleasing. If your text go all the way to the edges of the screen your app will look ugly. The grids between the boxes is used for aligning elements inside your app. You don't want all your elements to be all sticking together, they will look ugly. Windows Phone development focuses greatly on design.

Hope that helped!

Song

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So this is simply for aesthetics?  It's not a guideline that my application elements are going to disappear off the screen if I don't put all of my elements within the grid boundaries? Please see the edit on the question to see what I want to achieve :)

Comment: Yes. It's for aesthetics. It's not a guideline that your application elements are going to disappear off the screen. The general idea is to match the guideline edges wherever you can. This might what you want it to look like [this](http://oi46.tinypic.com/29zpsty.jpg).